# Finding the instance of a specific string and first 2 letters of next string and switch their places in php

Tags: php

I have a specific string that is:

```
  <span style="color: green;">
```

I want a function that finds the instance of this string and then further finds whether the next string's first 2 characters are

I have the idea of searching it character by character, but it would take too long. Is there any shorter solution to it?

Input:

```
  ab <span style="color: green;">  </strong>
```

Output:

```
  ab </strong> <span style="color: green;">
```

The strong tag is just for an example, it could be /b, /i, /li or any other closing tag.

Comment: Please make your question clear "I have this" and "I need this".

Comment: I already knew the problem and I have mentioned that too in my question too, still you people are giving me the same answer. How can I accept such answers?

Comment: I just asked whether there is any solution to it or not and mentioned clearly that I cannot change my HTML and everybody is providing the HTML solutions

Comment: And of course I did not get my desired answer. Everyone should read questions first, before answering

Comment: What do you need with THIS question ?

Comment: I have a string that has this span tag and that string could have any closing tag after this span tag. I wan't that whenever such scenario occurs, that closing tag should be replaced by this span tag and this span tag with the closing tag.

Comment: Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this, i.e.:

```
$myHtml = <<< LOL
ab <span style="color: green;">  </strong>
LOL;   

$myHtml = preg_replace('%(<span style="color: green;">)(?:\s+)?(</.*?>)%i', '$2 $1', $myHtml);

echo $myHtml;

//ab </strong> <span style="color: green;">
```

---

It will work with any tag that comes after the span.

DEMO:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9dc934ece66856a92b041114140982dc822a6bec

Comment: Thanks a lot, You saved my time and code length as well.

Comment: If I want that whenever </span> comes in between and I want to just ignore it and move further with the checking and not to switch it's position, what change should I make?